# Administrative password doesn't work when I try to install applications

Tags: software-center, password, authentication

I have a problem. When I try to install something from the software center it tells me my password is incorrect. 
In my account, I just changed my password to 'None', since I don't want to be prompted any time I turn on my computer. 
However when in software center, even when I press enter (not type any password in) it still doesn't let me download - 'Your authentication attempt was unsuccessful. Please try again'.
I also tried with my passphrase.

Comment: can you access your computer with none password?

Comment: Did you change your password, or just turn on the "log in automatically on boot" feature?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set your password to something within the ubuntu requirements. Enter recovery mode through the grub boot entry and go down to "drop to root shell" then type " mount -o rw,remount /" then "passwd (username)" and enter your new password